# I can't seem to find a sci-fi book I read in the 90s called The Duelist

Tags: story-identification

It's about the teenage son of a great general turned political revolutionary on the interplanetary corporate government. When his father is killed he is jailed on a prison planet but his father was a duelist and the boy was incredible. Body and mind were so in tune he could move faster than could be seen, so he managed to break out and took the entire prison population with him, turning them into the core group of a new religion. Just an awesome story.

Comment: Not trying to sound like a grammar Nazi here but correct spelling might help : **Duelist**. Unless you actually mean **Dualist**, which is a word I don't recognize.

Comment: @Daft A dualist is one who adheres to some kind of [dualism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dualism). I'm pretty sure the OP means duelist.

Answer (score 14):

There is a book series by Rutledge Etheridge called the Duelist Series:

- Legend of the Duelist: [Link](http://www.fictiondb.com/author/rutledge-etheridge~legend-of-the-duelist~104369~b.htm)
- The First Duelist: [Link](http://www.fictiondb.com/author/rutledge-etheridge~the-first-duelist~105006~b.htm)
- Brother John: [Link](http://www.fictiondb.com/author/rutledge-etheridge~brother-john~117944~b.htm)

Your memory of the plot seems to align with "The First Duelist" summary: *"It was to be the first great galactic expedition. Nineteen days later, only one passenger was alive. His survival was the most significant event of the twenty-second century...
Sixteen-year-old Simon Barrow was branded an intruder, and sentenced to death on the asteroid Mercator, an infamous prison for the condemned.
In this desperate colony of thieves, murderers, and anarchists, Simon Barrow came to lead a new force of elite combatants--the Duelists. Their first mission: liberation from Mercator. Their second: invade the future with a vengeance..."*

[image]

As a side note, apparently Rutledge Etheridge is a pseudonym, and the author's actual name is unknown.

Comment: OMG, I would hope that "*Rutledge Etheridge*" was a pseudonym.  Worst name ever.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Tossing [Berkeley Breathed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Breathed) into that ring... :)

Comment: I'm wondering if it is an anagram.  I'm personally not good at letter re-arrangement games though.